# How to save each field in repeater field as model

Tags: laravel, octobercms

There are 2 models: `Form` and `Prog`.

`Form` can have many unique `Progs`. It's not like movies and genres, it's like   user and his messages.

There is table for `Forms`, for `Progs` and cross reference table `forms_progs` (it has 2 columns - form_id and prog_id).

I added repeater field (`Progs`) to form of model `Form`. If I have, for example, 3 `Progs` how can I create models of them first and then connect their ids with id of the `Form`?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of One-To-Many associations where a single model owns any amount of other models. You can do it in 2 tables.

*For Form model:*

```
class Form extends Model
{
    public function progs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Prog');
    }
}
```

*For Prog Model:*

```
class Prog extends Model
{
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form');
    }
}
```

Once the relationship has been defined, you can retrieve they "dynamic properties" in both direction.

```
// Get progs in form _id = 1
$progs = App\Form::find(1)->progs;

foreach ($progs as $prog) {
    //..
}

// Get Form Title in Prog _id = 1
$prog = App\Prog::find(1);

echo $prog->form->title;
```

Comment: I add 'progs' with repeater field (OctoberCMS) when I create `Form` model.
In `Form` model I added $hasMany property (https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#one-to-many)

After trying to save model it tries to find `form_id` column in `progs` table. I added the column. Now the model is saving successfuly, but it doesn't save `progs` from repeater field. Just in case, I set fillable all fields of Prog model (it didn't help). Also I tried to set repeater field jsonable.

Could you help, @Ken Wong?